# Is there a way for a Github Page application consume a local xlsx file that does not show in the repository?

Tags: vue.js, github, github-pages

I uploaded a front-end mapping platform on Github Pages which I developed with vue.js + vue2leaflet.
The thing is, on my local environment I consume the data on the map from my local database.
With Github pages only hosting my front-end, I wanted to consume a .xlsx file instead of the database. But I cannot expose this file on github since it has sensible information.

The github repository is [this.](https://github.com/rafacribas/frontend-map) (Currently consuming a api just to showcase.)

The GithubPage is using the gh-pages branch. I deploy after building it and pushing the dist folder to this branch.